# SVG Path not working on Safari ( Desktop and Mobile )

Tags: svg

Since yesterday I've been trying to find a solution for my SVG Path..

It’s not displaying on Safari (Desktop & Mobile).

Before creating this post, I checked few topics where someone was facing the same problem, but by applying the recommended solutions in theses topics, it didn’t change anything.

I also added the xlink: in front of the :href which apparently should solve the problem, but there is no change..

I would appreciate your help

```html
<svg width="auto" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 1770 1229.5">
    <path id="curve" fill="transparent" d="M20,293.2 C20,770.9 407.3,1158.2 885,1158.2 C1362.7,1158.2 1750,770.9 1750,293.2 V71.2 H20Z"></path>
    <text width="100%" style="scale(-2,-2) translate(-100,-100);">
       <textPath
       startOffset=79.4751%
       opacity="100%"
       style="
       font-size: 40px;
       fill-opacity: 0;
       stroke: #030303;
       stroke-width: 1px;
       stroke-opacity: 1;" 
       
       
       xlink:href="#curve">Réserver un appel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Réserver un appel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Réserver un appel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Réserver un appel
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Réserver un appel
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Réserver un appel
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Réserver un appel
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Réserver un appel
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Réserver un appel
       <animate
        attributeName="startOffset" from="0%" to="-13%"
        dur="12s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Works for me on Safari desktop.

Comment: @Robert Longson It's not working on mine.

Here's the website where the SVG appears https://www.valoare.fr/

It's supposed to be animated bottom the rounded div at the middle of the page 
before "Les Prestations" 

Working perfectly on Chrome/Mozilla not on Safari..

Comment: @RobertLongson here's the preview : https://vimeo.com/736877485
Left screen is Chrome
Right screen is Safari

Comment: As I said, I agree your site is broken in Safari. The testcase in this question is not, however. I'm afraid you're unlikely to find someone willing to debug your website.